# Model without a Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I created a model which contains a proxy to load a single record and its takes no params. I don't want to use a store since I'll never have more then one record. I create an instance of the Model but can't figure out how to tell it to call and load the record from the server. This is the only example I could find, but I don't have an id to pass.

```
User.load(123, {
success: function(user) {
    console.log("Loaded user 123: " + user.get('name'));
}
});
```

Also I'm making and ajax call and not a rest call in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[load(id, [config])](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load)** is static and will <s>return</s> provide you with a new record instance. It uses the proxy that was set via **[setProxy(proxy)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-setProxy)** (also static). Per default it will send a read request with the params `id: 123`. The static method allows you to set some default callbacks within the optional config object. These callbacks are needed to get the instance of the loaded record (or the error).

**How it works**

```
// create a Model class
Ext.define('MyApp.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

// apply a proxy instance
MyApp.User.setProxy(/*YourAjaxProxy*/);

// prepare a handler
var cb = function(model, op) {
    // log the new model instance
    console.log(model);
};

// get a instance
MyApp.User.load(123, {
    scope: this, // should be the scope of the callback (cb)
    success: cb
});
```

Not what you need? Just comment...

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: Did just that and it seems to work only issue is that it doesn't seem to register with the Ext.ModelManager. Which I need so I can access else where in the application.

Comment: @theboulderer I guess you have a missunderstanding of the `Ext.ModelManager`. Other as with the `Ext.StoreManager` the ModelManager store the Model configuration and not a instance. Again in contrast to the StoreManager you cannot use it to receive a ModelInstance applicationwide. For that you will need to write your own Manager class or use a simplified approach by add a property of type MixedCollection to the Ext.app.Application (f.e. ModelMgr),register the appProperty (f.e. appProperty:'Instance', appName: 'App').You can no call App.Instance.ModelMgr.get(User'). Add them within the callback

Answer (score 0):

Just make an Ajax request and store the result in a variable.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: '/data/get',
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        requestID: 'XXXX',
                        connName: 'yyyy'
                    },
                    success: function (responseData) {
                       var countResult = Ext.decode(responseData.responseText);                      }
                });
```